# Existence of stationary stochastic processes with very high correlation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, inequalities

A [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336659/existence-of-isotropic-random-field-with-slow-covariance/336662#336662) was recently asked by a new user, SomeoneHAHA, and then deleted by the user, after receiving an answer. I think the question and the answer (QA) to it may be of interest to some users. Therefore, I am resurrecting the QA. Here is the question, in a bit brushed-up form:

Let $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb R}$ be a normalized [wide-sense stationary stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Stationarity) in $\mathbb R$, so that $g(t):=\text{Cov}(X_s,X_{s+t})$ does not depend on $s$ and $g(0)=1$. 
By [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem), $g$ must then be the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of a probability distribution.

The question is: Is it possible that $\frac{1-g(t)}{t^2}\underset{t\to0}\longrightarrow0$?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
This is only possible when $g=1$ identically. Indeed, otherwise, by Hoeffding's [Lemma 3.2, page 217](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512603), one of the following two alternatives must take place:

(i) $g$ is the characteristic function of a degenerate distribution, so that $g(t)=e^{itx}$ for some real $x\ne0$ and all real $t$, and hence $\frac{1-g(t)}{t^2}\underset{t\to0}\longrightarrow0$ is false;

(ii) there are positive real numbers $b$ and $c$ such that $1-|g(t)|\ge ct^2$ for $|t|\le b$, which again precludes $\frac{1-g(t)}{t^2}\underset{t\to0}\longrightarrow0$, because $|1-g(t)|\ge1-|g(t)|$.